# Editing session variable in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to edit `$_SESSION` variables, but why does it take 2 refreshes to change? Am I doing something wrong? What should I do differently?

For example:
I have `$_SESSION['lang'] = en` 
With a form button I will give it a new value.
After clicking the button the page refreshes, but session variable stays the same.
When I refresh my page again, the variable changes.

CODE:

```
if (isset($langBtn) && $langBtn === 'et') {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'et';
} elseif (isset($langBtn) && $langBtn === 'en') {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
}
```

First button click refreshes the page and when I click somewhere else or refresh page then the `$_SESSION['lang']` changes.

Comment: Please include more of your code and identify the noted issues in it.

Comment: Added a little snipped what changes session value @kchason

Comment: Thats a bit too short of a snippet. Is this happening before or after you are outputting the session variable on the page? Are you using `session_start()` anywhere? Are you interrupting the output with a header redirect possibly? Lots of reasons surrounding this behavior.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I have a login page, after successful login session_start(); is called in user class and $_SESSION['lang'] is defined with the value from database. Also, user is redirected to another page.